# Can I use Fluent Validation with Dependency Injection without having the automatic validation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using "FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" library (Version="11.4.0") for a .Net Core 6 project.

I have my validator registered in my program file:
`services.AddScoped<IValidator<SomeModel>, SomeValidator>();`

My code is something like this:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IValidator<SomeModel> _someValidator;

        public SomeController(IValidator<SomeModel> validator)
        {
            _someValidator = validator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validator));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SetSome([FromBody] SomeModel model)
        {
            //The SomeValidator is triggered before this, while being injected into the constructure.
            ValidationResult validationResult  = await _someValidator.ValidateAsync(model);
        }
    }

    public class SomeModel
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    public class SomeValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeModel>
    {
        public SomeValidator(/* Need to use DI here */)
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

How can I disable the automatic validation?

I was looking for a solution where i didn't have to use `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` because supposedly is going to be deprecated. The only way I was able to disable the automatic validation was to remove the validator injection and do something like this:

```
ValidationResult validationResult  = await new SomeValidator.ValidateAsync(model);
```

But has mentioned earlier I wanted to use DI inside my validator without the need to pass the parameters.

Comment: Hi, I cannot understand the DI here, which do you want to DI? Do you mean you do not want to pass the model here:`await new SomeValidator.ValidateAsync(model);`?

Comment: I want to be able to do this `await _someValidator.ValidateAsync(model);`, the problem is not the way I pass the model, but the way I access the ValidateAsync without initialising the validator.

Comment: Are you trying to say that Validator is getting triggered before the request is hitting the controller? @RodrigoMartins